# Explore convergence of improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ax}}{(1+x)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

First I thought of Dirichlet's principle, but we don't have a bounded function. Then, I assumed, we can use it after decomposition in parts: $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ax}}{(1+x)^2}dx = \lim_{t\to\infty } e^{-ax}  \arctan(x)\bigg|_0^t + \frac{1}{a}  \lim_{t\to\infty } \int_{0}^{t}e^{-ax}  \arctan(x)dx,$$but it seems pointless to me. What should be done?

Comment: The integrand is bounded on the domain by $e^{-ax}$, which clearly has a convergent integral.

Comment: Tip - for multiplication use `\cdot` , not `*`. For arctangent, use `\arctan` not `arctg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

For $a>0$ $$0<{e^{-ax}\over (1+x)^2}\le{e^{-ax}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-a x}}{(x+1)^2} \, dx=\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-a x}}{(x+1)^2} \, dx+\int_1^{\infty } \frac{e^{-a x}}{(x+1)^2} \, dx=$$
$$=\left(1-\frac{e^{-a}}{2}-a e^a \Gamma (0,a)+a e^a \Gamma (0,2 a)\right)+\left(\frac{e^{-a}}{2}-a e^a \Gamma (0,2 a)\right)=1-a e^a \Gamma (0,a)$$
which exists only if $a>0$